# Javascript to Pull Specific Record from JSON Array

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON array like this:

```
[{"Name":"Bob", "EmployeeID":1234, "StartDate":"12/01/2011"},
 {"Name":"Jim", "EmployeeID":4432, "StartDate":"01/12/1997"},
 {"Name":"Heather", "EmployeeID":6643, "StartDate":"07/09/2010"}]
```

How can I use Javascript to find and retrieve the record for Jim, searching by EmployeeID (4432)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `filter`:

```
var records = [{"Name":"Bob", "EmployeeID":1234, "StartDate":"12/01/2011"},
   {"Name":"Jim", "EmployeeID":4432, "StartDate":"01/12/1997"},
   {"Name":"Heather", "EmployeeID":6643, "StartDate":"07/09/2010"}];

var result = records.filter(function(r) { return r["EmployeeID"] == 4432 })[0]||'No record found';
```

A search function could be implemented as follows:

```
function findByEmployeeId(records, employeeId) {
   return records.filter(function(r) { return r["EmployeeID"] == employeeId })[0]||null;
}
```

In general, if you have any control over the data, I would recommend changing the structure to make your life easier. If you use the following structure you can access the record directly by using `records[employeeId]`:

```
{ "1234" : {"Name":"Bob", "EmployeeID":1234, "StartDate":"12/01/2011"},
  "4432" : {"Name":"Jim", "EmployeeID":4432, "StartDate":"01/12/1997"},
  "6643" : {"Name":"Heather", "EmployeeID":6643, "StartDate":"07/09/2010"} }
```

Comment: or find() if you can to use ECMAScript 6 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: When I try your function example, the console says "records.filter is not a function..."

Comment: Not every browser has this yet, but I'd recommend checking out [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) that gives you a lot of search functionality.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control over the data... this is being sent as a feed from a different server

Comment: @Adam this would occur if `records` is not an array, or if you're using IE 8 or lower. If the former, pass an array for `records`. If the latter, try the polyfill at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: @Adam : I put the example in a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/n264dq28/1/ - I hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

First of all, Your JSON object is incorrect; it's missing two commas. It should be:

```
[{"Name":"Bob", "EmployeeID":1234, "StartDate":"12/01/2011"},
 {"Name":"Jim", "EmployeeID":4432, "StartDate":"01/12/1997"},
 {"Name":"Heather", "EmployeeID":6643, "StartDate":"07/09/2010"}]
```

So, you can access EmplyeeID 4432 like this:

```
var myJSONobject = [{"Name":"Bob", "EmployeeID":1234, "StartDate":"12/01/2011"},
 {"Name":"Jim", "EmployeeID":4432, "StartDate":"01/12/1997"},
 {"Name":"Heather", "EmployeeID":6643, "StartDate":"07/09/2010"}];

function showJSON() {
  alert(myJSONobject[1].EmployeeID);
}
```

Comment: OP wants to retrieve the employee by its `EmployeeID` – this retrieves it by its array index.